# Resultset object is giving simultaniously false and true when I applied check. (Database)

Tags: sqlite, java-8

I am working on a project where I am searching w.r.t Sender name. I am getting and confusing answer for set.next() while testing . Simultaneous true and false returns . I am using IntelliJ IDEA idea anyways . I was testing so even if I am wrong it should be returning either true or false and not both of them.

```
public void getDataAllbySendername(String Sendername) {
    try {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Statement statement = mConnection.createStatement();
        ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from Tableit3 where sender LIKE '" + Sendername + "';");
        //  System.out.println("yes man yes it is");
        System.out.println(set.next());
        if (set.next()) {
            System.out.println("true man true");
            System.out.println(set.next() + " 3rd time");
            Setextension(set);
        } else
            System.out.println("nothing at all");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}    

//Below is the code having the testing part from above given

 System.out.println(set.next());
        if (set.next()) {
            System.out.println("true man true");
            System.out.println(set.next() + " 3rd time");
            Setextension(set);
        } else
            System.out.println("nothing at all");
```

Below is Out put screen result, first saying true and yet going else statement

`true
nothing at all`

After commenting first output statement

```
//System.out.println(set.next());
        if (set.next()) {
            System.out.println("true man true");
            System.out.println(set.next() + " 3rd time");
            Setextension(set);
        } else
            System.out.println("nothing at all");
```

Below text on Output screen

`true man true
false 3rd time`

please someone can clarify me for what is happening , where am a throwing up a blunder--__--

*Setextension(set) is a method  I created a method to prevent code duplication for set.get methods.

Answer (score 0):

The answer whom I found out after more testing is  set.next is true for the first time and later on wards false because of `set.next()` is kind of an iterator kind of. It will give true for the first 1 but false for others only if there is no more data after that first 1. `set.next()` increments on each call.

Comment: Congratulations. You found out, what [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) tells you. Reading the documentation would have taken less time than writing your question on Stackoverflow. As an advice for the future, you should generally try to find out what the purpose of a method is, e.g. via reading the documentation, before using it.